# Python - Split genetic data with uppercase and lowercase elements of a string with no spaces into list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm dealing with filtering large chunks of genetic data. For ease of reference, we'll use a string of shorter elements as such:

```
geneData = 'gggtacaccaaGGCCTATAACAttacatCTACATTGGAtcaggatccaaaATTAAGGAA'
```

I want to split this string into a list of all the uppercase sections as words (and eventually with the lowercase portions), so this is my needed output:

```
cleanedExons = ['GGCCTATAACA', 'CTACATTGGA', 'ATTAAGGAA']
```

This is similar to how I have split up words in the past from a sentence and I've been trying to adapt the code to split the string into a list with little success. Here is my current code:

```
def Exon_Split(string):
    IntronLetters = 'gcat'
    L=string.split(IntronLetters)
    cleanedExons=[]
    ExonLetters = 'GCAT'

    for e in L:
        word = ''
        for c in e:
            if c in ExonLetters:
                word += c
        if word!=ExonLetters:
            cleanedExons.append(word)
    print(cleanedExons)
Exon_Split(geneData)
```

This is the output I get. As you can see, it does not get split into the desired elements:

```
['GGCCTATAACACTACATTGGAATTAAGGAA']
```

Is there a way to make python see these chunks of uppercase as "words"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a problem? Use regex:

```
import re

geneData = 'gggtacaccaaGGCCTATAACAttacatCTACATTGGAtcaggatccaaaATTAAGGAA'
pU = re.compile('[A-Z]+')
pL = re.compile('[a-z]+')
cleanedExons = pU.findall(geneData)
# repeat with PL
```

I did some performance testing, out of boredom:

```
# 10000000 iterations
# regex split: 40.23s
# regex findall: 26.53s
# the itertool version posted in another answer: 163.82s
```

so `re.findall` is the winner.
Credits for `findall` go to @Tomothy32, the initial version I posted used `split`.

Comment: Nice use of regex, but couldn't you simply use `findall`?

Comment: thanks @Tomothy32, it is cleaner and faster (because no list comprehension], I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.groupby` is a way:

```
import itertools

geneData = 'gggtacaccaaGGCCTATAACAttacatCTACATTGGAtcaggatccaaaATTAAGGAA'

cleanedExons = [''.join(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(geneData, key=str.isupper) if k]
print(cleanedExons)
# ['GGCCTATAACA', 'CTACATTGGA', 'ATTAAGGAA']
```

For lowercase, just change `str.isupper` to `str.islower`.